# pyqt designer and layout for central widget

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

I started new clear Main Window project,

There are 4 Objects: MainWindow, centralWidget, menubar, and statusbar.

I need to set default layout inside the window, so probably for centralWidget.

But I didnt found way how to do it.
I can get LayoutWidget with some particular size into centralWidget.

But I want to set layout for the whole centralWidget.

Comment: Are you using QDesigner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click anywhere within your `centralWidget` go to the Lay Out sub menu and select the Layout you want. This will be applied automatically to all contents of your `centralWidget`.

In order to see how it works place inside it 2 or 3 push buttons and try changing the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Add some widgets to the central widget first.

Then select the central widget and use the "Layout in a Grid", "Layout Vertically", etc buttons on the toolbar to add a main layout.

The layouts in the "Widget Box" side-bar are used for adding child layouts to a main layout.